# React-financial-charts displays svg outside div

Tags: reactjs, svg, canvas

I'm relatively new to React and I'm trying to create a sort of dashboard for Cryptocurrency prices.

I'm using `react-financial-charts` to generate an OHLCV chart within a `ResponsiveReactGridLayout`.

However, the svg always displays outside the grid. Can anyone help with how I could fix this:

Here is the code: https://github.com/astronights/market_analysis_tool_evaluation-ui/blob/master/src/components/Home/Home.tsx where I render my Component that contains the ChartCanvas.

```
<div key="candlestick" className="home-card">
        <div ref={canvasRef} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
          {canvasRef.current ? (
            <Candlestick
              coin={coin}
              width={canvasRef.current.clientWidth}
              height={canvasRef.current.offsetHeight}
            />
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
```

and here is the code for the chartCanvas: https://github.com/astronights/market_analysis_tool_evaluation-ui/blob/master/src/components/Home/Candlestick.tsx

```
return (
    <ChartCanvas
      height={props.height}
      ratio={1}
      width={props.width}
      margin={{ bottom: 50, top: 100, left: 50, right: 50 }}
      padding={0}
      seriesName={`OHLCV prices - ${props.coin.coin}`}
      data={prices}
      xScale={scaleTime()}
      xAccessor={xAccessor}
      xExtents={xExtents}
     />
```

As you can see in the image, the SVG chart generated seems to be going outside.
[image: UI Rendered image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding these lines of CSS.

```
.react-financial-charts {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```